# How to pass parameter to the constructor of the XAML-Page

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I need to pass some argument or parameter to a Page's constructor, it seems I could not find a way to do it.

```
This is only open the page. How to pass a parameter to the constructor of the Page1?

 this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page1));
```

Comment: It would be nice to see what you've tried, and what you're trying to accomplish so people can better respond to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As utterly strange as your question is, here's your answer. This is not a XAML question. This is simply a C# question. Creating a custom constructor on Page3 would be a simple as this:

```
public sealed partial class Page2 : Page
{
    public Page2()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var p3 = new Page3(e.Parameter);
        // do something
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
}

public sealed partial class Page3 : Page
{
    public Page3(object parameter)
        : base()
    {
        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Please note two things:

1. I have never heard of anyone doing things like this. Having said that, it doesn't make it wrong. It just makes it very strange.
2. Page 3 has NavigationCacheMode set to Required. If you intend to navigate to Page3 someday, you will need this set in order to guarantee the proper instance. Let me explain, when you Frame.Navigate(Type) you are navigating to a type, and not to an instance. That means your local instance of Page3 (as p3 in this case) isn't the resulting page you will actually navigate to. That is, unless, you set Cache mode like this. There is no option for Frame.Navigate(p3).

Good luck.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Actually, I was doing printing in P2. I need all controls with data in P3(design for invoicing) show up in P2 when passing parameter to P3 to get data from SQLite DB and Add P3 control in P2. So thinking to use Navigate method. However found the solution, I use use Framework element. Your code does provide help. Thanks

Comment: Had you only said that. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override OnNavigatedTo handler event and get parameters from it. Read something about NavigationService, eg. http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Passing_parameters_while_navigating_between_pages_on_Windows_Phone

Comment: I dont want to pass parameter this way. Actually this is my condition : p1 -> P2  at P2 I want to open P3 BUT without going there. At P2, I want to pass parameter to P3 constructor to get data and At P2 I show P3 elements in P2.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you should use MVVM for XAML applications. In such case you should set value to ViewModel and set it as context for your Page.